# Using variable substitution in replace.gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

How do I include a variable in the 'replace' portion of `gsub`?

```
replace.gsub(/#{year}","1/, '#{year}","b')
```

This outputs:

```
=> #{year}","b
```

Let's say year = 2013. I want it to output:

```
=> 2013","b
```

Comment: You need double quotes to do variable substitution, so replace `'#{year}","b'` with `"#{year}\",\"b"`.

Comment: String interpolation between single quotes doesn't work in Ruby. I make that mistake all the time.

Comment: Thank you! I spent too long trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to Blender's answer, you can use an alternate way of writing strings to avoid having to escape quotes:

`replace.gsub(/#{year}","1/, %{#{year}","b})`

where %{} is another way to write a string literal that you can do string interpolation in.